# Is there any neat way to slice and combine dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, filtering

I have at the moment 4 dataframes each in which I have 4 variables "Hardness [N]", "Thickness [mm]" , "Weight [mg]" and "Diameter [mm]". I wish to filter the data from each of these variables using only the data within the 10th and 90th percentile for each variable. Then combine the data back again so only the data which is within the 10th and 90th percentile for all 4 variables is used.

I have currently been doing this as follows

```py
h190 = np. percentile(df["Hardness [N]"], 90)
h110 = np. percentile(df["Hardness [N]"], 10)

clean_hardness_1 = df["Hardness [N]"][(df["Hardness [N]"] >= h110) & (df["Hardness [N]"] <= h190)]
```

This is obviously lengthy as there are 4 variables of interest and 4 dataframes. Not to mention that I have no idea how include only data that satisfies this 10-90th percentile for all 4 variables for each dataframe to then plot and do some subsequent calculations for (i.e dataframe 1 plot, dataframe 2 plot etc..) which again doing this as I have been is lengthy.

This is the sort of plot I have created with my raw data in which each different colour is data from an experiment at different conditions. I wish to do this again with the filtered data:

[image: plot]

So any help on any aspect of this would be much appreciated!
(Apologies if I butchered any of the language I'm fairly new to python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can construct and use a mask for a given dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Hardness [N]": np.random.rand(n),
        "Thickness [mm]": np.random.rand(n),
        "Weight [mg]": np.random.rand(n),
        "Diameter [mm]": np.random.rand(n),
    }
)

# Compute quantiles on all columns and combine q1 and q9
mask = (df.quantile(0.1) < df) & (df < df.quantile(0.9))


res = df[mask] # will contain NaNs
res = res.dropna()
# OR
res = df[mask.all(axis=1)] # combine boolean mask for all columns
```